# How do you select a table cell by its index?

Tags: javascript, html

I know there is a way of accessing sequential elements, but I'm not sure how to access them by index. Is there a way to do it?

I'm looking for something like:

```
document.getElementById('table1').cell[1]
```

Comment: I may not have made myself clear enough, sorry. What Im looking to do is select a table by id, then accessing the cell elements within the table by sequential numbering (cells are not assigned id's)

Comment: Ah, you meant access them by their `index`.

Comment: Ah index is the term Im looking for, that helps! :]

Comment: `document.getElementById('table1').rows[0].cells[0]`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To access a cell by its row index and cell index within that row you can use:

```
var rowIndex = 0;
var cellIndex = 1;
document.getElementById('table1').rows[rowIndex].cells[cellIndex];
```

This will access the second cell (index 1) in your first row (index 0)

If you want to just use cell index (and not keep track of rows) and have it iterate through the cells in each row, you can do this, but only if every row has the same number of cells. The following code would access the fourth cell in the table (index 3) whether it's in row 0, 1, or 3; as long as each row has the same number of cells:

```
var cellIndex = 3;
var table = document.getElementById('table1');
var num_columns = table.rows[0].cells.length;
var cell = table.rows[Math.floor(cellIndex/num_columns)].cells[cellIndex % num_columns];
```

Comment: Please revise your code getElementByid I believe should be getElementById   "I" uppercase JS is case sensitive :-)

Answer (score 6):

A table's [`.rows` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) provides access to the rows. A row's `.cells` collection provides access to that row's cells. Both use zero-based indexing and have a `.length` property. So:

```
var table = document.getElementById('table1');

alert(table.rows.length);                // number of rows
alert(table.rows[2].cells.length);       // number of cells in row 3

alert(table.rows[2].cells[5].innerHTML); // contents of 6th cell in 3rd row
```

Comment: Missing open parenthesis in the first line.

Comment: Nice clean solution, Goes down to IE8 ? _(+'d this)_

Comment: @Zuul - it will work at least as far back as IE 5 (I can't remember any further back than that).

Answer (score 3):

To restrict the query by id to the tree of an element you can use `querySelector`:

```
document.getElementById('table1').querySelector('#cell1');
```

But that's just redundant when you can simply do

```
document.getElementById('cell1');
```

**Edit**: to better answer to OP's request, one can access sequentially to the cells of a table in this way:

```
document.getElementById('table1').tBodies[i].rows[j].cells[k];
```

This selects the `k`-th cell of the `j`-th row of the `i`-th body of the table.
If your table has just one `<tbody>` element (like usual), or you want to access to the cells indipendently from their `<tbody>`, you can omit the `.tBodies[i]` part.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.querySelector('table td'); //Done. IE8 and above supported.
                                    //Only the first one will be selected.
```

```
document.querySelector('#table1 td'); //First cell in #table1

document.querySelector('#table1 td:nth-child(3)'); //Third cell in #table1
document.querySelectorAll('#table1 td')[2];        //or this
```

Comment: You'll get zero results because of the child selector. Remove it, and you'll get all `td` elements in all tables instead of only the desired one.

Comment: Looks good. +1 And I was wrong about selecting all `td`'s. Thought you were using `qSA` instead.

Comment: @Derek, if relevant, I was trying that with a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/QLdJW/)! Complement your answer with it. Oh, +1 ;)

Comment: I don't get it. Are you trying to make it work in IE8 too? Because the third statement doesn't work in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Give the `<td>` cell an id:

```
<td id="mycell">
```

Then you can access the DOM object by using `getElementById()`:

```
document.getElementById('mycell');
```